# Binding ObservableCollection<string> with converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-8

I have a GridView, which has its ItemSource Property binded to an ObservableCollection of strings.

I have a DataTemplate for the items, wich has a TextBox defined like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DataItem" Text="{Binding}" />
```

It works fine. But now I want to use a converter, so I'm writing it like:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DataItem" Foreground="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Text="{Binding}" />
```

And this doesn't work. It looks like the binding needs a path.

How can I bind to an element of an ObservableCollection of string if I want to use a converter?

Comment: what is the error message? How did you implemented the Converter?

Comment: it makes more sense if you add your converter code and "MyConverter" code in XAML.... and like Marco said we don't need "," for sure.. the exception is related to something else

Comment: That code just doesn't compile, I can't have a comma there, but if I take it out I get  'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Comment: Did you try `Path=.` in your binding?

Comment: @Rachel Yes, but still getting 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Comment: @anderZubi Can you post the full text of your exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the comma:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DataItem" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I Get 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Comment: Sorry, I was trying it simultaneously in Windows 8 and Windows Phone, and it works in Windows 8. However doesn't in Windows Phone.